# Redirect to hidden url in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect

I have 2 servers, one of them is public and another is hidden from my users. First one can see the second one in the local network but users can't access the second computer on public network.

I want redirect some URLs (with a specific pattern) form public computer to the hidden. Hidden URL may returns any headers on response.

Currently I implement this feature by redirect streams, but the problem is the response (to end-user/client) hasn't all headers.

hidden response:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: filename="0.jpg"
Content-Length: 38903
Content-Range: bytes 0-38902/38903
Content-Type: image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 05:11:48 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 Apr 2016 06:28:17 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

response after redirect streams:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 38903
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2016 05:14:06 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

My code is something link this:

```
private void redirectGalleyStream(long diskId, String code, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
    final InputStream is = new URL(Settings.i().getVodServer() + "/downloadGalleryImage" +
            "?diskId=" + diskId + "&code=" + code).openStream();
    fastCopy(is, response.getOutputStream());
}


public static void fastCopy(final InputStream src, final OutputStream dest) throws IOException {
    try {
        final ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(src);
        final WritableByteChannel outputChannel = Channels.newChannel(dest);
        fastCopy(inputChannel, outputChannel);
    } finally {
        try {
            src.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        try {
            dest.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}

public static void fastCopy(final ReadableByteChannel src, final WritableByteChannel dest) throws IOException {
    try {
        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * 1024);

        while (src.read(buffer) != -1) {
            buffer.flip();
            dest.write(buffer);
            buffer.compact();
        }

        buffer.flip();

        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            dest.write(buffer);
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            src.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        try {
            dest.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

how can I have all headers in client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.

public static void fastCopy(String url, HttpServletResponse response,
                                HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();

```
    Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {
        final String headerName = headers.nextElement();
        conn.addRequestProperty(headerName, request.getHeader(headerName));
    }

    // Cast to a HttpURLConnection
    if (conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (code < 300) {
            Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                final String key = entry.getKey();
                if(Objects.equals(key, "Transfer-Encoding")) continue;
                String value = String.valueOf(map.get(key));
                if (value != null && value.length() > 0)
                    value = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                response.setHeader(key, value);
            }
            fastCopy(conn.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
        }
        response.setStatus(code);
    } else {
        System.err.println("error - not a http request!");
    }
}
```